# Is Firefox adding some invisible padding or margin to my absolutely positioned :after triangle?

Tags: css, sass, pseudo-element

I'm a little frustrated with the positioning of a CSS triangle on the :after pseudo-element which appears correctly in Chrome and Safari but appears to have a little extra padding or margin in Firefox.

First, screenshots:
[image: screenshot of broken chevron in firefox and chrome]

The top screen is how "Choose a Subject" appears in Firefox, the bottom how it appears in Chrome and Safari. Obviously this is purely cosmetic, but I'm going for that chevron look.

Here is the markup (for the first item, the darker-blue item is another li):

```
<nav class="menu pill-menu inline" role="navigation">

<!-- Major Category
======================
--> <ul>

    <li class="has-subnav primary">

      <input type="checkbox" id="primary-menu" class="checkbox-toggle"/>
      <label class="label" for="primary-menu">                                      

        Choose a Subject

      </label>                                     
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is the Sass:

```css
.pill-menu {

  & > ul > li { display: inline-block; }
  .primary > .label,
  .secondary > .label {
    @include css-transition(all, .2s, ease-out);    
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: .5em;
    position: relative;
  }

  .primary > .label {
    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  }

  .primary > .label:after {          
      border-top: 18px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 18px solid transparent;
      border-left: 18px solid $light-blue-object; // TODO: Abstract This  
      content: "";        
      height: 0; 
      right: -1em;
      top: 0;
      position: absolute;        
      width: 0;
      z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

I've tried several different things: using an :after pseudo-element, I used as I am now right: -1em; I've also scrapped than and tried left: 100%; I set the triangle to a :before element and tried an assortment there. I'm stumped.

I tried changing up the fonts, hardcoding the font-size in pixels, mucking with the padding and the margin: nothing I can think of has any effect on that little space.

I appreciate your thoughts.

In case it matters, I am using normalize.css.

Additionally, I would like to add that both Chrome Dev Tools and Firefox Inspector [or whatever they call it ...] show no difference in inherited, computed, or generated styles. They appear the same in every way.

I'm just stumped. Let me know if there's other information I can provide.

**Update**
At your request, the compiled CSS:

```css
.pill-menu .primary > .label:after {
  border-bottom: 18px solid transparent;
  border-left: 18px solid #50afdf;
  border-top: 18px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  right: -1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.pill-menu .primary > label {
  background-color: #50afdf;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: .5em;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide actual HTML (not PHP) and CSS (not SCSS)? We need to see what's actually happening.

Comment: Please share HTML and SASS via http://sassbin.com/

Comment: I've pealed away the smattering of PHP and added the compiled CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not margins *or* paddings, but whitespace.  Just remove the unnecessary spaces/newlines/tabs inside your label.

http://cssdeck.com/labs/v2f8qedp

```
<!-- Major Category
======================
--> <ul>

    <li class="has-subnav primary">

      <input type="checkbox" id="primary-menu" class="checkbox-toggle"/>
      <label class="label" for="primary-menu"> Choose a Subject</label>                                     
    </li>

  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: See also:  http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/.  Using comments to hide whitespace caused by multiple opening/closing PHP tags might be your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Unfortunately, even putting everything on one line (i.e., `<li class="has-subnav primary"><input ... [etc]><label class="label" for="primary-menu">Choose a Subject</label></li>` ) doesn't seem to affect the positioning of the absolutely positioned arrow.

Comment: The space is removed in the demo for me in Firefox (22).

Comment: Thanks @cimmanon for the link. I didn't quite know what to search in css-tricks but I definitely figured this would be addressed. I'll tweak wp_nav_menu() to eliminate whitespace in its output as well as in my own logic. I appreciate that it worked in your demo and you may be right that I didn't eliminate all the whitespace. I'll keep this updated as I iterate through the steps. Thanks!

Comment: If the solution works in the demo but not in your own code, then you haven't provided enough code to fully replicate the problem.

Comment: I came back around to correct for my accepted answer. It took some digging, but @cimmanon was right - whitespace around the was treated differently by all the browsers. In the PHP that was generating the label / menu, the whitespace was inherited from some of the indenting and commenting in the code for the devs. Once compressed, everything worked fine without any browser hacks.

Answer (score 0):

Tested this out on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8gBVq/1/). Seems to solve the issue. Can you try at your end?

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
    .pill-menu .primary > .label:after {
        right: -.9em;
    }   
}
```

Comment: **This works.**

A couple of things: 1.) Wow. I have never encountered @-moz-document url-prefix() before, and honestly I'm super satisfied to solve this problem this way. 

2.) So, in general, do you know if this potentially might actually be just how FF handles things? Just curious.

Comment: This is a very poor way to solve the problem.  The value of -.9em is just a [magic number](http://css-tricks.com/magic-numbers-in-css/).  It works in this instance, but the fact that you need it for one particular browser should be a red flag that you've done something wrong somewhere.

Comment: @mschofield Not sure if that's just how FF handles things.

Comment: @cimmanon Agreed, not an ideal solution but I'm not sure it's all that unusual to come up with 'hacks' for browsers. Hence the need for things like modernizr and the like.

Comment: Or even normalizer. I agree with @cimmanon regarding the danger of relying on a hack, and I'll keep this question updated if I find another solution. I consider it a quick fix, but like you I try to avoid magic numbers. cimmanon's demo below definitely seemed to work in the demo, but I just couldn't seem to replicate it live. I *did* fix that part in our shame.scss file (which, so far, only includes this one piece - which I think is a fairly good sign).

Thanks for both of your help!